# Adding html format on tinymce visual editor

Tags: admin, tinymce, visual-editor

Need to add more html format tag to TinyMCE Editor as visualized below

[image: tinymceeditor - highlighted **Format** dropdown]

Using Wordpress 3.6.1
Can't found any good example/guide for these modification.
Another solution welcome.

Thanks & Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

I Googled [`wordpress mce filter`](http://www.google.ca/search?q=wordpress+mce+filter), and it led me pretty directly to a [TinyMCE Custom Styles tutorial](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles) on the Codex.

It's not a simple thing -- you have to, for starters, enable a hidden button in TinyMCE called `styleselect` -- but it looks like the tutorial is fairly complete.

Is that what you're looking for?

[A sample is available on TinyMCE's 'Try It' section, too.](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php)